# Loop associating each locations to each months with R

Tags: r

I'am trying to build a loop in order to associate different locations and several months.

Here below a simplification of my code with only 2 locations and 3 months:

```r
require(lubridate)

seq_monthly = function(from,length.out) {
  return(from %m+% months(c(0:(length.out-1))))
}
 
location<-as.data.frame(c("Paris", "London")) # The code for the locations

firstday_dates= as.data.frame(seq_monthly(as.Date(paste0("1901-01-01")), length.out= 3)) # first day of each month

lastday_dates=as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("1901-02-01"), length=3, by="1 month") - 1) #last day of each month 

# Loop 
for (d in 1: nrow(location)) {
  for (t in firstday_dates){
    for (j in lastday_dates){
        url<-paste0(d, t , j)
          }}}
```

The output it gives is :

```r
[1] "London 1901-01-01 1901-01-31"
[2] "London 1901-02-01 1901-02-28"
[3] "London 1901-03-01 1901-03-31"
```

However what I need is:

```r
[1] "Paris 1901-01-01 1901-01-31"
[2] "Paris 1901-02-01 1901-02-28"
[3] "Paris 1901-03-01 1901-03-31"
[6] "London 1901-01-01 1901-01-31"
[7] "London 1901-02-01 1901-02-28"
[8] "London 1901-03-01 1901-03-31"
```

Thank you very much for your help,
Kind regards,

Comment: Where does function `seq_monthly` come from? It's not in base R, nor in other CRAN packages (based on cursory look).

Comment: Can you add the packages involved in your script to the code above?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added the package and the function seq_monthly to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```r
sort(apply(
    expand.grid(location[, 1], paste(firstday_dates[, 1], lastday_dates[, 1])),
    1,
    paste, collapse = " "))
#[1] "London 1901-01-01 1901-01-31" "London 1901-02-01 1901-02-28" "London 1901-03-01 1901-03-31"
#[4] "Paris 1901-01-01 1901-01-31"  "Paris 1901-02-01 1901-02-28"  "Paris 1901-03-01 1901-03-31"
```

Explanation: `apply(..., 1, paste, collapse = " ")` is the `for` loop in disguise, concatenating the location with the dates. `expand.grid` creates all combinations between `location` and the concatenated dates.

PS. I don't get the point of the `as.data.frame` calls in your sample data, as they turn a vector into a single-column `data.frame` and seem unnecessary.